# Slim framework 2.0 - redirect not working

Tags: php, slim

Redirect not working in Slim framework 2.0

```
try{
    $db->updatePassword($checkAuthentication['token_id'],$email,$password);   
    $res = $db->updatePassword($email,$password);   
    if($res['success'] == USER_PASSWORD_UPDATE_SUCCESSFULLY) {
        $app->flash('message','Form submitted!');
        $app->redirect($app->urlFor('thanks'));  
    }else{
        $app->flash('errors', 'Error while updating password');
        $app->redirect($app->urlFor('resetpassword',
            array(
               'encrypt_url' => $resetPasswordToken
            )
        ));  
    }

} catch (Exception $ex) {
    $app->flash('errors', $ex->getMessage());
    $app->redirect($app->urlFor('resetpassword',
        array(
           'encrypt_url' => $resetPasswordToken
        )
     ));
}
```

Here `$app->redirect($app->urlFor('thanks'));` doesn't work, and goes to the `catch` part.

We are use group for routing.

```
   $app->group('/web', function () use ($app) {
    // Version group
      $app->group('/user', function () use ($app) {

         $app->post('/updatepassword', function () use ($app) {
              // our code
         });

         $app->get('/thanks', function () use ($app) {
             $app->render('thanks.php', array(
                 'pageTitle'             => 'Thanks page'               
             ));
        })->name('thanks');

      });
   });
```

Give me a suggestion to **redirect to thanks page** with **flash success message**.

Answer (score 0):

If it goes to the `catch` block then it means `$db->updatePassword($checkAuthentication['token_id'],$email,$password);` throws an exception.

When that happens everything else following in the `try {}` block gets skipped and execution goes to the `catch{}` block.